# Is it safe to use RSA private key to encrypt a message

Tags: java, security, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

I want to distribute encrypted message, that only I can encrypt, but everybody can decrypt. I am using following code to perform the task. It works but I want to know if there are any security issues with it?

I know that normal usage is to use RSA public key to encrypt and private key to decrypt (but my use case is the reverse). Also I don't want to use java.security.Signature here.

Use-case:
I want to send configuration files from server to clients via email without the recipient being able to read the configuration in clear text. The application which had the server public key during the installation will be able to decrypt the configuration file once it is imported into configuration directory.

```
public static final String ALGORITHM = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";

public Cipher createCipher(final int encryptionMode, final Key key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    cipher.init(encryptionMode, key);
    return cipher;
}

public byte[] encryptString(final String text, final PrivateKey privateKey) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    return createCipher(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey).doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}

public String decryptString(final byte[] msg, final PublicKey publicKey) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    final byte[] decrypted = createCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey).doFinal(msg);
    return new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
}

// me 
final PrivateKey privateKey = ... read from file ...
final byte[] msg = encryptString("my-secret-text-that-everybody-can-read-but-only-I-can-generate", privateKey);

// other person
final PublicKey publicKey = ... read from file ...
final String text = decryptString(msg, publicKey));
```

Comment: *"Also I don't want to use java.security.Signature here"* Why? That's what you should use here if you want to sign something. That's what you're doing here isn't it?

Comment: You want to use a *digital signature*, but you don't want use the class for this, why?

Comment: Because I am sending configuration file from my server to my app and I don't want the normal user to read it in clear text or to be able to modify it.

Comment: What's the point in an encrypted message that everyone can decrypt?  That doesn't provide any confidentiality.  If the point is to prove that the message is really from you (since no one else has your private key), that's exactly what digital signatures are for, but you specifically said you don't want to use a signature.  It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you want digital signiture, sign with PrK, if you want to have confidentiality, sign with the PuK of the receiver. If you want both, then use an envelope, hence sign with both.

Comment: The point is that I can "push" configurations from the server down to the application without app user to be able to alter or read the configuration. The digital signature requires that the original message is provided in clear text, (is it really true?) The @meskobalazs proposal to use the receiver public key is good, but I don't want to have public/private keys on receiver (the app) side.

Comment: The client has to be able to decrypt, otherwise it cannot use the configuration. You have just discovered why DRM solutions cannot work, even in theory :)

Comment: Yes the client application will have my public key, but it won't have any public/private key pair on its own. The idea is I create the configuration encrypt it, send to the client (via email for example). The human who receives the email is not able to read the configuration, but once he/she puts the configuration file into configuration directory the application starts to use it next time it is started.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although the question contains code this really is a conceptual question about [cryptography](http://crypto.stackexchange.com), where it has been [asked before](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/29030/1172)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Maarten Bodewes for his comment that answers my question.

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although the
>   question contains code this really is a conceptual question about
>   cryptography, where it has been asked before –  Maarten Bodewes

From the [link](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/29030/1172) that he provides, the answer to my question is: "No, you generally cannot swap the public and private keys."

It simply jeopardize the security of RSA by using small prime number in public exponent. Here is the detailed answer:

> Your public key consists of a public exponent and a modulus. The
>   modulus should be known to the person doing the encryption. The public
>   exponent - in general - is a relatively small prime such as 3 or 65537
>   (Fourth number of Fermat). So given the modulus all an attacker has to
>   do is guess the public key. It's very easy to factor pretty small
>   exponents (I've written software to generate public keys given a
>   private key). The exponent of the private key on the other hand
>   consists of a number that is about as large as the modulus. It cannot
>   be easily factored; the security of RSA relies on this fact.